# Knockout js string format index in template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am currently working on some Knockout js templating stuff. My requirement is I need to set the name of a field (input) with a combination of string and the index value of the row.
For example "xxx3".

I tried two options.

```
'xxx' + ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(viewModel.mycollection, $data)
```

and

```
'xxx' + $index
```

The first option always gives '-1' for my index value and the second option doesnt work
becasue seems like I can only use the $index value without any string concatenation.

Could someone let me know if I can concatenate a string value to $index value in knockout so that I can set that to the name property of an input field.

The final result I want should be like this.

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" 
   data-val-required="The XXX field is required." id="XXX" type="text" name="XXX3">
```

Here is how my template looks like.

```
<table id ="editorRows" class="table">
        <tbody data-bind='template: {name: "rowTemplate", foreach: Rules }'></tbody>
    </table>

    <script id="rowTemplate" type="text/html">
        <tr data-bind="attr: { id: RuleKey }">
            <td>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="Name" type="text" data-bind="value: Name, attr: {name : 'Rules[' + $index + '].Name'}" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-bind="attr : { 'data-valmsg-for': 'Rules[' + $index + '].Name'}" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
</tr>
</script>
```

Comment: Post your template code.

Comment: `$index` only works in the context of a `foreach` binding. Are you using it in the right places?

Comment: Why you are doing `attr: {name : 'Rules[' + $index + '].Name'` it. Is `attr : {name : Name } is not working or you want name like Rules[0].Name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$index` is an observable, so you would need to call it to retrieve the value.  So assuming you are trying to set the values of the attributes to literally `Rule[0].Name`, you'd do this:

```html
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="Name" type="text"
       data-bind="value: Name, attr: {name : 'Rules[' + $index() + '].Name'}" />
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true"
      data-bind="attr : { 'data-valmsg-for': 'Rules[' + $index() + '].Name'}"></span>
```

Comment: Perfect...that's exactly what I needed. Thanks Jeff. Do you happen to know why my first option always gives '-1' for the index??

Comment: I'm not sure under what context that binding is in so I can't really give you an answer there. It could be a number of things: `$data` could have been wrapped in an observable, `viewModel.mycollection` may not have existed in that context (which usually leads to binding errors), or `viewModel.mycollection` was an observable array so you accessed it incorrectly (you need to call it to get the contents of the array). Remember this, if your binding expression is complex, you need to call on _all_ observables or you will have problems.